# Symfony, How to use DenyAccess with Doctrine object?

Tags: function, symfony, routes

I want to control the same user access on some methods in my controller.
Currently, I use this :

$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ACCESS', $this->Player($toolRepository));

However I am forced to use this line and inject the ToolRepository into each method ...

What would be the easiest way to do it?
I saw that there was the IsGranted annotation but my subject needs to be a doctrine object to control access with my Vote.

```
/**
 * @Route("/player")
 */
class PlayerController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="player")
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function Player(ToolRepository $toolRepository): \App\Entity\Tool
    {
        $playerTool = 'TestTool2';
        $tool = $toolRepository->findOneBy(array('libelle' => $playerTool));
        if (!$tool) {
            throw new Exception('Tool : ' . $playerTool . 'not found!');
        }
        return $tool;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/main", name="player")
     * @IsGranted ("ACCESS", subject="tool")
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function mainPlayer(PlayerRepository $playerRepository, ToolRepository $toolRepository): Response
    {
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ACCESS', $this->Player($toolRepository));

        $players = $playerRepository->findAll();
        return $this->render('player/player_mainpage.html.twig', ['players'=>$players]);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel.html#component-http-kernel-kernel-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this ressource should answer you: [Symfony voters](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html).

You'll put your security logic in your custom voter which will be called in every function of your controller (or every methods where you want to control access) `isGranted()` function.

Calling your `Player()` function is a easier way to do this for beginner, you can keep like that but you shouldn't put it in Controller and use a Service instead .

Edit:

You may store your ToolRepository as Controller private property and inject it in a `__construct()` method so you don't have to inject ToolRepository in each method

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Symfony voters helped me a lot. I modified my question because I have another small problem. Thanks

Comment: You may store your ToolRepository as Controller private property and inject it in a `__construct()` method so you don't have to inject ToolRepository in each method.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if there would be a way to control access with the @IsGranted annotation? 
I was thinking by putting the subject = the doctrine object return by Player() method ($tool).


* IsGranted ("ACCESS", subject = "$tool")

I don't know how to get $tool from the annotation.
If there is no way I would use private property.

Comment: In this case I'm not sure about the possibility to do so but I don't think it's viable. This mean you need to call your `Player()` function from the annotation and the only way I see this is something like `@IsGranted ("ACCESS", subject="PlayerController::Player()")` but the method should be static and I don't know about static method in SF Controller. 

Whatever, in both case your access control will use one line of code. In my opinion I would stick with private property.

Comment: I'll stay on private property then. Thank you very much for your help it helped me a lot !

Comment: You're welcome ! You may consider accept my answer so the issue is marked as closed ? Ty.